# function inside an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside an object but it isn't executed. Where did I go wrong.
JS:

```
switch(sometext){
case "GetStatus":                
                AgentReply = {
                    IsCustomer: false,
                    //UserText:"in process"
                    UserText: function () {
                        alert("test");
                        var text = "";
                        switch ($scope.LanguageId) {
                            case "1":
                                text = "is in process";
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                text = "test message";
                                break;
                        }                        
                        return text;
                    }
                }
break;
}
```

This code was working fine. But now I have conditions for 'UserText'. So, commented the original code and wrote a function to get the desired message for 'UserText'. But the alert never pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should execute function, add `()` after `}`, like so

```
UserText: function() {
    alert("test");
    var text = "";
    switch ($scope.LanguageId) {
        case "1":
            text = "is in process";
            break;
        case "2":
            text = "test message";
            break;
    }
    return text;
}()
```